# Installation of libv8 gem on OSX 10.15.4 Catalina fails

Tags: rubygems, libv8

I'd like to install "zammad" (see https://docs.zammad.org/en/latest/install/source.html) on my iMac but fail. 

**Error message as follows:**

```
An error occurred while installing libv8 (6.7.288.46.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '6.7.288.46.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.


In Gemfile:
  mini_racer was resolved to 0.2.4, which depends on
    libv8
```

**I tried various ways with no success. My last approach based on homebrew:**

1. **xcode** is installed, latest version **including command line tools**
2. Installed **v8@3.15 via homebrew** (see https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/v8)

   `brew install v8@3.15`
3. Set **path and compiler flags**

   `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15/include"`
4. Started **installation via gem**

   `gem install libv8 -v '6.7.288.46.1' -V -- --with-system-v8`

**Installation fails with the following error message:**

```
Error: Command 'cipd ensure -log-level error -root /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/vendor -ensure-file /var/folders/nz/3kvygfq95mg7nbhvvdd8wwqh0000gn/T/tmpq1sLRH.ensure' returned non-zero exit status 1

________ running 'cipd ensure -log-level error -root /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/vendor -ensure-file /var/folders/nz/3kvygfq95mg7nbhvvdd8wwqh0000gn/T/tmpq1sLRH.ensure' in '.'
Error: failed to resolve package version (line 5): bad version (not an instance ID, a ref or a tag): "M56jPzDv1620Rnm__jTMYS62Zi8rxHVq7yw0qeBFEgkC".
Running: gclient root
Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "managed": False,
    "name": "v8",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 306, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 301, in main
    return run(options, spec, root)
  File "/Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 295, in run
    return checkout.init()
  File "/Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 137, in init
    self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)
  File "/Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 82, in run_gclient
    return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 71, in run
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('gclient', 'sync', '--with_branch_heads')' returned non-zero exit status 1
/Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:79:in `block in setup_build_deps!': unable to fetch v8 source (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:77:in `chdir'
    from /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:77:in `setup_build_deps!'
    from /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:36:in `build_libv8!'
    from /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/ext/libv8
/Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/bin/ruby -I /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20200524-61596-1m99g20.rb extconf.rb --with-system-v8
Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/hollomey/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.5.0/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/gem_make.out
```

**Does someone know how to do it right?**

Thanks for your support

Florian

Comment: Did you find a solution?